# Batch Scripting - Search for value in text file and copy word next to it

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

Currently writing a batch program but I seem to be having a difficult time with string manipulation. I need help scanning through the contents of the Output.txt file below, in search of the the word ssudmdm. wherever the word is found, i then need to retrieve the com value on the same line, to the right and store it in a variable. 
I am aware that there are a few examples on the site, however I have have tried implementing them with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:-----------------------------------------------

```
@ECHO OFF

:: Use local environment copy
SETLOCAL
::regedit.exe /S VM_Putty_Settings.reg

:while1

reg QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM" > Output.txt

@start /wait FIND /C /I "ssudmdm" Output.txt

if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (  
    timeout /t 2 >nul
    goto :while1
    )


for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('find /i "ssudmdm" output.txt') do set var=%%a

reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\VM_Putty_Settings" /V SerialLine /T REG_SZ /D "%var%" /F

pause
start Putty.exe -load VM_Putty_Settings < nul >NUL 2>NUL


ENDLOCAL
GOTO:EOF
```

Output file----------------------------------

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM
    \Device\Serial0    REG_SZ    COM1
    \Device\Serial1    REG_SZ    COM2
    \Device\ssudserd0000    REG_SZ    COM5
    \Device\ssudserd0001    REG_SZ    COM6
    \Device\ssudmdm0000    REG_SZ    COM7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it all in one statement, without your intermediate file.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query hklm\hardware\devicemap\serialcomm /v *ssudmdm* ^| find /i /v "end of search"') do set var=%%a
```

If you must have the intermediate file for some reason:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('find /i "ssudmdm" output.txt') do set var=%%a
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the reply. Just a quick question, in the case of multiple ssudmdm, would the code above just replace the contents of var??

Comment: Also i have also included my current code with your solution and it seems to work great. However, as you can see implementing the solution without the intermediate file would require modifying the "Reg Query" and "@start" commands. I guess what i'm trying to ask is how would can i use a variable instead of a text file for those commands?

Comment: If there are multiple lines, then each loop through the `for` statement will overwrite the var. i.e. you will get just the last line. To avoid the file. `:while` `set var=` `for...` `if not defined var ( timeout... goto...)` `reg ...`